# Perform the three figures on different TIKZ commands

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Perform the three figures on different TIKZ commands. If it is a rectangle and a circle grows its radius within that rectangle, the radius starts at zero and can go to the diagonal of the rectangle.
I would like information on how to get started, where should I start this figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using `arc` instead of `plot`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{3}
\def\b{5}

\begin{scope}[xshift=-7cm]
\draw (0,\b) rectangle (-\a,0) arc(180:90:\a)
node[pos=.6,sloped,above]{$C(H)$};
\draw[|-|,xshift=3mm] (0,0)--(0,\a) 
node[midway,right]{$P$}; 
\draw[|-|,yshift=-5mm] (0,0)--(-\a,0)
node[midway,below]{$H$};
\draw[|-|,yshift=-1cm] (0,0)--(-\a,0)
node[midway,below]{$P$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\draw (-\a,0) rectangle (0,\b) arc(90:180:\b)
node[pos=.32,sloped,above]{$C(H)$}
node[pos=.7,sloped,above]{$C(H)^*$}--(-\a,0);
\draw[|-|,xshift=5mm] (0,0)--(0,\b) 
node[midway,right]{$Q$}; 
\draw[|-|,yshift=-5mm] (0,0)--(-\b,0)
node[midway,below]{$Q$};
\draw[|-|,yshift=-1cm] (0,0)--(-\a,0)
node[midway,below]{$P$};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{sqrt(\a^2+\b^2)}
\draw (0,0)--(-\a,\b)
node[midway,left]{$H$} 
rectangle (0,0)--(0,\c) arc(90:180:\c)
node[pos=.2,sloped,above]{$C(H)^{**}$}
node[pos=.7,sloped,above]{$C(H)^*$}--cycle;
\draw[|-|,xshift=5mm] (0,0)--(0,\b) 
node[midway,right]{$Q$}; 
\draw[|-|,yshift=-1cm] (0,0)--(-\a,0)
node[midway,below]{$P$};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[border={1mm 1mm 1mm 1mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\R{2}
\def\H{4}
\def\W{2}
\draw [red,domain=90:180] plot ({\R*cos(\x)}, {\R*sin(\x)});
\draw[blue](0,0)rectangle(-\R,\H);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\R{4}
\def\H{4}
\def\W{2.2}
\draw [red,domain=90:180,name path=A] plot ({\R*cos(\x)}, {\R*sin(\x)});
\draw[red](0,0)--(-\R,0);
\draw[blue,name path=B](0,0)rectangle(-\W,\H);
\path [name intersections={of=A and B,by={E, F}}];
\draw[green](0,0)--(F) node[midway,above,sloped]{H};
\draw [fill=red,draw=none] (F) circle(1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

You can change 'R', 'H' and 'W' parameters to get the desired result.